Determining Left-Hand Side Type Inference in TypeScript
I'm encountering difficulty with TypeScript's type inference when trying to determine the left-hand side type of a variable assigned to the result of a method call on an Iterable class. Here's a simplified version of the issue:
const iterable1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const collectAsSet: Set<number> = intoIterable(iterable1).collect(); // expected { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
const iterable2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const collectAsArray: number[] = intoIterable(iterable2).collect(); // expected [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

To achieve this, I'm trying to somehow infer the types Set<number> and number[] from the return object of the intoIterable method. Is it possible to do this directly within the method of the intoIterable return object?
p.s. I know how to implement it by passing parameters to .collect(). However, I'm interested in exploring a method that accomplishes this within the method chaining approach.
function x<T>() {
    return {} as T & (T extends { foo: number } ? { foo: 42 } : { foo: "42" });
}
const n: { foo: number } = x();
const s: { foo: string } = x();
console.log("N", n, "S", s);


I'm very confused. Is this question just about typings or is the implementation supposed to work that way also? There is 100% absolutely no way to implement anything called intoIterable() such that const y: Set<number> = intoIterable(x).collect() will produce a Set but where const y: number[] = intoIterable(x).collect() will produce an array. At runtime the TS type system is completely gone, so both of those are just const y = intoIterable(x).collect(); since the two calls are identical at runtime there isn't any possibility for this to work, even if you can describe it with types.

The realization of .collect() might depend on type. But after I've ensured that it's not possible, I will change the implementation

(see prev comment) I could imagine writing the code at this playground link and it... kind of... does what you're asking. But there's no implementation, and there really can't be one.  So what do you want to see happen here? Should I write up an answer that says "this typing does what you want but there's no way to implement it and you should just pass params to collect()"? Or do you want to [edit] the question to make it more clear how you'd like it to be addressed?

As mentioned there's no way to infer types from the left-hand operand of an assignment
You could though implement ArraySet with a proxy (the set part should be cached in a more advanced implementation, also a construct proxy could be added to add constructor typing):
Playground
type IArraySet<T> = Array<T> & Set<T>;

class ArraySet<T>{
    constructor(arr: T[]){
        return new Proxy([...arr], {
            get(obj, prop, proxy){
                if(prop in Set.prototype){
                    const set = new Set<T>(obj);
                    const member = set[prop as keyof Set<T>];
                    return typeof member === 'function' ? member.bind(set) : member;
                }
                return Reflect.get(obj, prop, proxy)
            }
        });
    }
}

function intoIterable<T>(iterable: T[]){
    return {
        collect(){
            return new ArraySet<T>(iterable) as IArraySet<T>;
        }
    };
}

const iterable1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const collectAsSet: Set<number> = intoIterable(iterable1).collect(); // expected { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
console.log(collectAsSet.has(1));
const iterable2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const collectAsArray: number[] = intoIterable(iterable2).collect(); // expected [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
console.log(collectAsArray[0]);

